# A Seeming contradiction

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following result

> Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and $A_i$ be a decreasing sequence of topologically connected compact subsets. Then $\cap A_i$ is topologically connected.

I have an issue with that. I seem to have myself convinced that I have constructed a counter-example. Here is an extract from my working (it is a screenshot as it involves diagrams)

[image]
**Redaction**
The reason why I think what I am left with is not connected is because I can define f(x,y)=x. The image of this function is then $[-1,0) \cup (0,1]$ which is not not an interval, and hence what I have should not be connected
Could anybody help me with this seeming contradiction?

Comment: Since they are compact, you will never entirely rip the rectangle.

Comment: Could you define what you are doing? You seem to be intersecting $A_i=[-1,1]^2\setminus(B_{a_i}(r_i)\cup B_{b_i}(r_i))$ for some points and radii $a_i,b_i,r_i$. Is that right? It's probably for the best if you specify the $a,b,r$ precisely

Comment: Your intersection is connected, like the union of two tangent *closed* half disks.

Comment: You are not being precise in your construction, but it seems that the middle point of the ractangle belongs to all $K_n$? And so it belongs to the intersection. Therefore the projection $f(x,y)=x$ won't help you showing that it is disconnected. Especially since it is connected.

Comment: @freakish I think you are right. thought that it wont belong to the limit, however, by definition it must. Ah!!! Thank you for this comment and thank you to everybody else. If you can post this as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from the drawings that in each $K_n$ those balls keep getting closer and closer to the middle of the rectangle $O$. But they never reach it. And so $O\in K_n$ for each $n$, thus $O\in\bigcap K_n$. This means that the projection $f(x,y)=x$ won't help you, because the image is connected. And in fact the intersection $\bigcap K_n$ has to be connected by the result you've quoted.